# Can't assign an image to a Nullable ImageView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, imageview, android-imageview

How can I set an image to ImageView?

The idea of my app is to show the different type of RecyclerView's view holder according to the data class in a RecyclerView. Data classes look like this:

```
abstract class Thing(open val title: String, open val body: String, open val pic: ImageView?)

data class Movie(override val title: String, override val body: String): Thing(title, body, pic = null)
data class Book(override val title: String, override val body: String): Thing(title, body, pic = null)
data class Game(override val title: String, override val body: String, override val pic: ImageView?): Thing(title, body, pic)
```

Also, I have a MainFragment where I am adding the data manually. Here I am trying to give the name and the description of a game, and also to set the particular image to a game_pic ImageView:

```
class MainFragment: Fragment() {
private val mMoviesBooksGames = listOf(
  Game("Dixit", "Give the perfect clue so most (not all) players guess the right surreal image card.", game_pic.setImageResource(R.drawable.alias) as ImageView)
  }
}
```

How I declare the GameViewHolder where my `game_pic` is:

```
class GameViewHolder(inflater: LayoutInflater, parent: ViewGroup) :
    ThingViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.game_list_item, parent, false)) {
    private var mGameTitleView: TextView? = null
    private var mGameDescriptionView: TextView? = null
    private var mGamePicImageView: ImageView? = null

    init {
        mGameTitleView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.game_title)
        mGameDescriptionView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.game_description)
        mGamePicImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.game_pic)
    }

    override fun bind(dataToBind: Thing) {
        mGameTitleView?.text = ">> Book ${dataToBind.title}"
        mGameDescriptionView?.text = dataToBind.body
        mGamePicImageView = dataToBind.pic
    }
}
```

An error that I get after using `game_pic.setImageResource(R.drawable.alias) as ImageView` is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.recyclerview, PID: 822
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.recyclerview/com.example.recyclerview.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3555)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3707)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2220)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8019)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.recyclerview.MainFragment.<init>(MainFragment.kt:33)
        at com.example.recyclerview.MainFragment$Companion.newInstance(MainFragment.kt:67)
        at com.example.recyclerview.MainActivity.createFragment(MainActivity.kt:4)
        at com.example.recyclerview.MainActivity.createFragment(MainActivity.kt:3)
        at com.example.recyclerview.SingleFragmentActivity.onCreate(SingleFragmentActivity.kt:25)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7957)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7946)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3530)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3707) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2220) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8019) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 822 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Is there a typo? You don't set third argument, as its in the same quotes with body

Comment: your `game_pic` variable is null, can you post the code, where you declare it?

Comment: @Steyrix, I added the declaration. I basically declare it in the ViewHolder for my RecyclerView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data class Game(
    override val title: String, 
    override val body: String,
    override val image: Int)
```

modify the data class like this

```
override fun bind(dataToBind: Thing) {
    mGameTitleView?.text = ">> Book ${dataToBind.title}"
    mGameDescriptionView?.text = dataToBind.body
    mGamePicImageViewsetImageResource(dataToBind.pic)
}
```

after that write replace the code into your view holder like this

```
data class Game(
    "Dixit", 
    "Give the perfect clue so most (not all) players guess the right surreal image card.", 
    R.drawable.your_pic
```

)

then try to put this value in your Game cons.

Comment: Hi @Nik and thanks a lot of answering. Your code helped - it doesn't crash anymore, thank you! But I don't see the picture I set anyway.

Comment: Although, ```mGamePicImageView.setImageResource(dataToBind.pic)``` doesn't work since I am initializing ```mGamePicImageView = R.id.game_pic``` in my ```GameViewHolder``` class. ```.setImageResource()``` doesn't work on ```Int``` type

Comment: first, check the in an XML file that has used android: src attribute or not if yes then remove it & add android:scaleType=" centre crop" & try this **mGamePicImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drwable.your_pic)** if it doesn't work then change the drawable image maybe image is corrupted

Comment: thank you so much! Your solution helped a lot. Only I used ```dataToBind.pic?.let { mGamePicImageView?.setImageResource(it) }```  because I put ```abstract class Thing(open val title: String, open val body: String, open val pic: Int?)``` in the start.

Comment: I think you should make an extension function for similar views & you don't know how much it is useful and surprisable for you, It's so amazing, please refer online if you don't know about it

Answer (score 1):

The error says that your `game_pic` variable is null.

One workaround I can suggest without seeing your code:

```
private val mMoviesBooksGames = listOf( Game(
        "Dixit", 
        "Give the perfect clue so most (not all) players guess the right surreal image card.", 
        ImageView(this).apply { setImageResource(R.drawable.alias) })
)
```

Construct ImageView and set image resource on non-null instance.
Or you can initialize your `game_pic` somewhere in, for example, `onCreateView` method and therefore initialize your `mMoviesBooksGames` after that.

**UPD:**

1. You should not declare your Views as nullable.
2. You can set your image resource in another way.

First of all, you initialize your `mGamePicImageView` in `init` and then rewrite it in `bind`. Second, you can instead pass only drawable data to view holder, not a whole new ImageView.

I suggest you to redesign your data class:

```
data class Game(
    override val title: String, 
    override val body: String,
    override val imageDrawable: Drawable)
```

And then in bind method of viewholder

```
mGamePicImageView.setImageDrawable(dataToBind.imageDrawable)
```

And finally

```
private val mMoviesBooksGames = listOf( Game(
    "Dixit", 
    "Give the perfect clue so most (not all) players guess the right surreal image card.", 
    ContextCompat.getDrawable(this.activity, android.R.drawable.alias))
    )
```

Not that first argument of `getDrawable` is context, so pass your fragment's parent activity there. Second argument is drawable's id, I am not sure if you need prefix `android.`, so you can also try just `R.drawable.alias`.

Comment: Crashes with ```Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference```

Comment: I cannot avoid setting the ImageView as nullable because I have to put it as null in my other data structures.

Comment: @Lilya you don't need imageview parameter, use drawable instead. And also, data classes shouldn't know anything about Views, they represent only data which is set to the views, not the view itself

Comment: Exactly, they represent the data. And ImageView is the data I am passing to represent

Comment: @Lilya ImageView is the subclass of View, actually. Nik's answer suggested you the similar thing I wrote about in my answer.

Comment: Probably I did something wrong. Let me use your solution once again, please. I will update if that works

Comment: the app doesn't crash! Thank you so much :)  But the image is not visible so far. That's because I use ```abstract class Thing(open val title: String, open val body: String, open val pic: Drawable?)```. The thing is, I can't use non-nullable because my other data structures don't need the images. Or because something is wrong with my image. I don't know